# Rails Devise send password reset mail as delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, devise

I want to set the rails plugin **devise**'reset_password_instructions to **delayed_job**..but I tried many ways and failed.

I found a function password_controller#creat :

```
self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(params[resource_name])
```

I think the sentence used for send email to reset password.

I want to alter it like :

```
self.resource =  Delayed::Job.enqueue ApplicationController::MailingJob.new(:resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions, params[resource_name])
```

OK, it will return Syntax error...

Help me.. I don't know how to solve it.. thx.

Comment: Well, what's the syntax error? MailingJob should be a model, so you shouldn't be putting it inside a controller module, as your code suggests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125564/rails-devise-delayed-job

Answer (score 2):

I use the [delayed_job_mailer](https://github.com/andersondias/delayed_job_mailer) plugin to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

on console:

```
Devise::Mailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(self.resource)
```

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if you explained what this does.

Comment: please try in rails c.
self.resource is object user that want to send confirmation email.
for example:
user = User.first
Devise::Mailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(user)