# Rails + Devise + delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I have a Rails 3 App using Devise on Heroku. Problem is I'm sending emails with Sendgrid and email delivery is slow, it makes the app hang. So I'm interested in using delayed_job to queue the email delivery in the background so my app is responsive to the user.

How can Devise be used with delayed_job? Any way to setup Devise to use delayed_job?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From Robert May: https://gist.github.com/659514

Add this to a file in `config/initializers` directory:

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Confirmable
      handle_asynchronously :send_confirmation_instructions
    end

    module Recoverable
      handle_asynchronously :send_reset_password_instructions
    end

    module Lockable
      handle_asynchronously :send_unlock_instructions
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Add that code in some file.rb in `config/initializers` directory.

Comment: This did not work for me perhaps due to the fact that this method is not supported if using Rails 3 mailers which devise probably uses.  See this link for more info: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job and go to the Rails 3 Mailers section

Answer (score 12):

According to the [Devise wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Send-devise-emails-in-background-%28Resque,-Sidekiq-and-Delayed::Job%29), the [devise-async](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async) gem will handle this for you. It supports delayed_job, resque, and sidekiq.

Answer (score 6):

I found that none of the above worked for me. I'm using Devise 2.0.4 and Rails 3.2.2 with delayed_job_active_record 0.3.2

The way devise actually talks about doing something like this in the comments in the code is to override the methods in the User class. Thus, I solved it like so, and it works perfectly:

app/models/User.rb

```
def send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(self)
end
def send_reset_password_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.reset_password_instructions(self)
end
def send_unlock_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.unlock_instructions(self)
end
```

Comment: over-riding these methods clobbers other functionality... it seemed to work, but did not set the reset_password_token on the user model see my solution

Comment: If you look at the code for send_reset_password_instructions in the latest Devise:
      # Resets reset password token and send reset password instructions by email
      def send_reset_password_instructions
        generate_reset_password_token! if should_generate_reset_token?
        self.devise_mailer.reset_password_instructions(self).deliver
      end
The suggestion above results in the password token not getting generated.

Answer (score 3):

this is the thing that worked for me:

in app/models/user.rb

```
  # after your devise declarations
  handle_asynchronously :send_reset_password_instructions
  handle_asynchronously :send_confirmation_instructions
  handle_asynchronously :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
```

you may not need all of them depending on which devise modules you are including

Comment: Works for me with Rails 3.2.16 and Devise 3.2.3.  I'm also using devise_invitable 1.3.4, for which I added `handle_asynchronously :deliver_invitation`.

Comment: Well, I commented too soon. I also had an override of `send_reset_password_instructions` in my User model. It didn't work right when run asynchronously. ZachBeta's [1/6/2014 comment on Github](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/58) led me to try `handle_asynchronously :send_devise_notification` which seems to handle everything including invitations. The Devise source code also has a [lengthy comment](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3d9dea39b2978e3168604ccda956fb6ec17c5e27/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L129-L174) on delaying queueing.

Comment: how to accomplish this for "devise_token_auth" gem ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Devise provides an easy way to do backgrounding of email delivery. However there are ways to be able to do that with DelayedJoy. DelyedJob provides a function "handle_asynchronously" which if injected into the DeviseMailer can ensure that deliveries happen in the background.

Try this in your config/application.rb

```
config.after_initialize do 
  ::DeviseMailer.handle_asynchronously :deliver_confirmation_instructions 
  # or
  ::DeviseMailer.handle_asynchronously :deliver!
end
```

You will need to experiment with that. You could also try to inherit the DeviseMailer and set it to deliver asynchronously in an initializer in config/initializer/devise_mailer_setup.rb or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

For [delayed_job_active_record](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/delayed_job_active_record/4.1.1) with **Devise** , just use the following . (add it to `user.rb model` )

```
handle_asynchronously :send_devise_notification, :queue => 'devise'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to authenticate any of the delayed_job tasks. Just have the Devise authenticated controller actions queue the email delivery to a library method.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [delayed_job_mailer](https://github.com/andersondias/delayed_job_mailer) plugin to accomplish this in Rails 2 apps. Not sure if it works with Rails 3.

Answer (score -5):

I have generally found it best to avoid any and all background-job task managers available for Ruby and Rails, period.  They suck.

Instead, I use crontab which is an ancient program and very good at its job.  Just make a script to do your dirty work every so often and tell crontab to run it at the right times using rails runner.  This keeps those pesky long-running tasks outside the run-time of the rest of your Rails application, but you still have access to the database and the whole Rails stack if you want/need it.

Comment: I disagree with the claim that "any and all background-job task managers" suck. Ruby Toolbox has a nice comparison on queueing options for Ruby: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/queueing.html

Comment: So say you have an import that puts new products or new info on products into you app. Now the new products need generate some metadata or what not. Are you going to add a flag to the products table so your cronjob can pick up on those items? How often do you run that cronjob? Every ten minutes? What if one execution run takes longer than 10 min. You'll have competing processes running. Seems more like what ever you try to hack up with crontab will just end up being a poor-mans-implementation of a job queue. Better of using a dedicated queue that won't crud up your database schema and models.